# CefSharp - Running JavaScript continuously in the background

Tags: javascript, c#, cefsharp, chromium-embedded

I would like to know if it possible to run a JavaScript script continuously in the background of a CefSharp application, having it start upon the application first opening and run until it is closed.

Specifically, I am utilising a JavaScript-based eye tracking library. Upon the application opening, the user needs to calibrate the eye tracking. Once calibrated, this script needs to run in the background sending tracking information to other pieces of JavaScript.

Currently, all JavaScript is loaded and executed on the main frame. So, when the user navigates to new pages using the browser, execution ends and all the JS is re-loaded and re-executed upon the frame loading again. This makes it so that the user is prompted to re-calibrate the eye tracking on each new page load, whenever I need it to be performed only once.

The JavaScript files that are re-loaded *need* to be re-loaded, as they interact directly with the DOM and so need to access the information of newly loaded pages.

It'd be preferable for these re-loaded JavaScript files to be able to interact directly with the continuously running background code, but it is also possible to establish communication through a WebSocket.

Currently, I am not sure if this is even possible and if it is I do not know how to go about it.

I attempted to spawn a new separate frame that is never re-loaded and running the background JavaScript there - but I did not get very far. The application I am building on does not currently support multiple tabs (there seems to be no UI available for it, etc), hence why I found it difficult to spawn a new frame that the user can interact with briefly.

Apologies for the lack of code snippets - many thanks in advance.

Comment: The first question should really be is what I'm attempting possible in Chrome? The first option I'd be investigating is https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers

Comment: Thanks so much for your response. It seems it would be difficult to start the eye tracking script from the web worker since they cannot access the usual global JS scope where that file would be loaded. Unless there is a way to send a message to a worker to allow it to call functions from a script in the regular scope, I'm not sure it'd work. Do you know if that's possible / if there is anything else I could look into?

Comment: Still struggling here. Tried to run the script in one tab and then create a new tab allowing the user to continue browsing and whatnot, but chromium stops execution of my script(s) when the executing tab loses focus/becomes inactive. Read about execution being slowed, but mine straight up stops. Any possible way to hack around this?

Comment: Are you using WinForms or WPF?

Comment: WPF. Managed to patch things together such that it works. Background tabs were being throttled as normal by Chrome but my script seemed to stop completely likely due to `requestAnimationFrame` calls being made to display the webcam feed. Setting the command line argument `--disable-background-timer-throttling` and replacing calls to `requestAnimationFrame` with `setTimeout` allowed the tab to run at full speed even when not focused/visible. Regardless, thanks for your help - if you have any more appropriate (less hacked together) ideas then please let me know.

Comment: You can use Bound Object to send json encoded data to your c# application. After calibrate your system, send that info to your C# application and, in each navigation, when you inject your script, inject also the calibration data.